# How to add an addition Of T to a System.Linq.Iqueryable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I was in the middle of writing this post, but to the great help of stackoverflow I found a hint that helped me solve my issue, but I wanted to post this in order to help other developers if they come accross this issue and are new to VB.NET, ASP.NET and MVC5.

I have a variable of type faqs declared as System.Linq.IQuerable(Of ViewModels.FaqViewModel)  'Note I created a FaqViewModel to pass the Model data that is needed to view.

However, there might be times when the query results are null, but I need to pass at least one item back to the view in order to show some results and return the original search query back to the search box.

Here is my code, what am I missing?

**VIEW** 
     --- @ModelType IEnumerable(Of CompanyName.ViewModels.FaqViewModel)

**CONTROLLER**
     
        Function SearchFaqs() As ActionResult
            Dim url As String
            Dim txtSearchTerm As String

```
        If Request("txtSearch").IsNullOrWhiteSpace() Then
            txtSearchTerm = ""
        Else
            txtSearchTerm = Request("txtSearch")
        End If



        url = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
        Dim faqs = (From f In _db.Faqs _
                   Where Not f.Hk_DeletedDt.HasValue _
                   And f.Question.Contains(txtSearchTerm) _
                   Or f.Answer.Contains(txtSearchTerm) _
                   Or f.Hk_DeletedDt = New DateTime(1900, 1, 1) _
                   And f.Active = 1 _
                   Order By f.CategoryId Descending _
                   Select New FaqViewModel With {
                                                .Question = f.Question,
                                                .Answer = f.Answer,
                                                .SearchTerm = txtSearchTerm
                                                })


        If Not faqs.Any() Then

            faqs.Union(Of FaqViewModel)(IEnumerable)

            '(New FaqViewModel With {
            '                                                .Question = "Your Search did not contain any results please try again.",
            '                                                .Answer = "",
            '                .SearchTerm = txtSearchTerm
            '                                                })



        End If

        Return View("Faq", faqs)

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

What I found to fix the problem.

**CONTROLLER UPDATED, simply converted to a .ToList !!! **

```
        <HttpPost>
    Function SearchFaqs() As ActionResult
        Dim url As String
        Dim txtSearchTerm As String

        If Request("txtSearch").IsNullOrWhiteSpace() Then
            txtSearchTerm = ""
        Else
            txtSearchTerm = Request("txtSearch")
        End If



        url = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
        Dim faqs = (From f In _db.Faqs _
                   Where Not f.Hk_DeletedDt.HasValue _
                   And f.Question.Contains(txtSearchTerm) _
                   Or f.Answer.Contains(txtSearchTerm) _
                   Or f.Hk_DeletedDt = New DateTime(1900, 1, 1) _
                   And f.Active = 1 _
                   Order By f.CategoryId Descending _
                   Select New FaqViewModel With {
                                                .Question = f.Question,
                                                .Answer = f.Answer,
                                                .SearchTerm = txtSearchTerm
                                                })**.ToList**


        If Not faqs.Any() Then
            **Dim noResultsFaq As New FaqViewModel
            noResultsFaq.Question = "Your Search did not contain any results please try again."
            noResultsFaq.Answer = ""
            noResultsFaq.SearchTerm = txtSearchTerm
            faqs.Add(noResultsFaq)**
        End If

        Return View("Faq", faqs)

    End Function
```